# WooCommerce Ajax add-to-cart not working with custom product box bundle product pluging

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle

I have a paid plugin named "**Custom Product Boxes**" with paid theme named "Blance".

The theme is using ajax cart update on click on add to cart. It is working the other simple or variable products.

But when we create a bundle product using "**Custom Product Boxes**" plugin with theme "Blance". it is not working.

It gives JavaScript console.log causes error:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

product url:- http://112.196.38.115:4030/beautifulforyou/index.php/product/custom-product/